# HTML content slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscript

I'm not skilled in advanced HTML, or any CSS at all, and I've done some research into making something I think is called a "content slider" (like the thing at http://www.redlighttraffic.org/, an anti-human trafficking organization), but I've come up short.

Looking at http://www.menucool.com/slider/content-slider I think it wants me to buy the code to use that slider, but what I need is one closer to the one used on the Redlight Traffic website I linked, and hopefully free... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The right direction is *that* way --> :D   - kidding aside, what is your question?  Are you wanting to buy the code or write it yourself?

Comment: My question is simply, how do I begin? Is there a tutorial somewhere? I don't even really know what to call this thing, besides "content slider", and I'm not sure that's the correct name.

Comment: @Codefun64 - jQuery is your friend.

Comment: I see you have an answer and thanks for clarifying.  The way I read the question didn't make it clear to me if you wanted advise on where to find the code like the site you mentioned (to buy or, even better, free) or if you wanted advise on how to build it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at this list, I'm sure you will eventually find what you need: http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-image-slider-slideshow.html

But if want to learn how it works and how to make one yourself then check out this article: http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-slick-auto-playing-featured-content-slider/

If you search something like "CSS content slider" or "jquery slider" or any combination of those keywords you will find hundreds of results that should help you

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I'll definitely read those.

Comment: @Codefun64 - You can also just make one very easily: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BLM64/

Answer (score 1):

HTML and CSS are both very small components of what you are trying to achieve. You need to look into what is known as Jquery, a javascript library. You can achieve this going over tutorials on youtube, or google "open source JQuery sliders." There are some really fantastic ones out there, including [nivo-slider](http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/).

You could make an open source one look like the example by rounding off the corners with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's been about a year and a half since I did some research on this myself, and I ended up going with both Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and Responsiveslides (https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js) back then after trialling a few different ones. About a year ago, I rewrote the site and now only use Responsiveslides.

What I liked about both was the cleanliness of the markup and they were easy to fit in a responsive design. What ended up giving responsiveslides the edge in the latest round of changes is the size: 1.4kb minified is pretty darn small, and in addition it did everything I needed from it (if you need it to do more, size will obviously increase). Jquery was part of the project anyway, so the overhead from loading that wasn't an issue for me.

Hope that helps!